# How to terminate a running process in matlab?

Tags: matlab, terminate

I have a pretty simple question: how can I terminate a running script in matlab using code, similar to using <kbd>CTRL + C</kbd>?

I want the program to stop running if a user enters incorrect digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If in debug mode, you can use `dbquit`.  if you're in the main function, `return` terminates and returns.  Otherwise use the `error` function.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `error` function. See `doc error` for more information.